# How to install a new website from bitbucket repository?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have a repository on Bitbucket and ı am working on local.

Now I want to install this website(respository) to my server under a www.domain.com.

How i can do this with ssh connection?

And I want to install same repository under different domains tah update when it is necessary

I am looking for possible ways for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to commit and push your local work to the remote branch (for example on `origin/master`).
2. Log in on your server via ssh (for more information, how to add your public key to your server [look here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id))
3. Clone and pull your repository on your server
4. If you want to have different versions or what ever on subdomains, you have to create own folders (for example `test` or `dev`) and clone and pull changes from a certain branch. (You have to change the entrance point of your subdomain to the folder `test` or `dev` if you want to have the subdomain `test.domain.com` or `dev.domain.com`.

Comment: it is nice your explications. Repository is already on Bitbucket. And i have already ssh connection to my website by cd public_html/domain.com.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if i could help you or answer your question :)